# Reduce bit-depth of PNG files from the command line

Tags: macos, command-line, png, bpp, bit-depth

What command or series of commands could I execute from the CLI to recursively traverse a directory tree and reduce the bit-depth of all PNG files within that tree from 24bpp to 16bpp? Commands should preserve the alpha layer and should not increase the file size  of the PNGs - in fact a decrease would be preferable.

I have an OSX based system at my disposal and am familiar with the `find` command so am really more keen to to locate a suitable PNG utility command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK the only PNG format that supports the alpha layer is PNG-24; Reducing the PNG to another format may require specifying a transparent color in a CLUT, which will not give you the output you want.

From the feature list on PNG's website:

- 8- and 16-bit-per-sample (that is, 24- and 48-bit) truecolor support
- full alpha transparency in 8- and 16-bit modes, not just simple on-off transparency like GIF

... which I read to mean that anything other than PNG-24 or PNG-48 does not support full alpha transparency.

Comment: Thanks - I was unaware of this PNG limitation so you have saved me some time.

Comment: @teabot Paletted PNGs *do* support full alpha transparency, see http://pngquant.org

Answer (score 6):

1. Install fink
2. Say "fink install imagemagick"  (might be "ImageMagick")
3. "convert -depth 16 old/foo.png new/foo.png"
4. If that did what you want, wrap it in a find call and be happy.  If not, say "convert -help" and RTF-ImageMagick-M. :)
5. Optional: "fink install pngcrush" and run that as a second pass after the convert pass.