# Combine png's into a PDF without rerasterizing

Tags: imagemagick-convert

I am using ImageMagick's `convert` to combine 6 PNG files into a PDF:

```
Bytes   File name
-----   ---------
44927   002.png
43507   003.png
71375   004.png
56448   005.png
61696   006.png
57694   007.png

# Both generate a 533,378 byte PDF
convert 00?.png OutputFile.pdf
convert 00?.png -density 200x200 OutputFile.pdf
```

The images are 200 DPI black & white scans from a flatbed scanner.  The PNG files total 335,647 KB, but the resulting `OutputFile.pdf` is 533,378 KB.

**Is this size inflation due to re-rasterization?**

**How can one specify to `convert` to keep the existing pixels?**

In case it matters, I am using Cygwin's ImageMagick 7.0.10.27-1 on Windows 10 64-bit (`cygcheck -p convert | grep -i imagemagick`).

Comment: The PNGS are already rasterized. But I suspect PDF will keep the raster images uncompressed as raw data (not formatted as PNGs) in the PDF vector shell. I do not know of any way to tell ImageMagick to keep them compress. You might look into other tools to convert raster images into PDF files

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that default compression occurs, just not enough to make up for the 8 bits per monochrome pixel.  The investigation of other tools will take time, so I'm resorting to `convert` for convenience.  I'll take the approximately 2x hit in file size.

Answer (score 0):

The `pdfimages` output below that there is some default compression (under the `ratio` column).  I recalled plumbing the depths of `convert` [some time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50539071/tools-run-from-unix-command-line-to-decrease-bit-depth-of-grayscale-images-in-pd).  The `depth` option did not reduce the bits per pixel.  From the tests below, neither does `depth` in combination with `monochrome`.  Additionally, it is odd that `monochrome` causes the DPI to change from 200 to 508 or 509.

One possible cause of file size inflation is the use if 8 bits/pixel.  From the previous tests of `convert` linked to above, it seemed that the compression squeezed out space wasted by the unwanted 8 bits per pixel.  From the PDF file sizes, however, it seem that if this is true, then it doesn't really make up for all of the file size inflation.

```
# 1st default, monochrome, 200dpi, depth 1, and combinations
convert 00?.png  default.pdf
convert -monochrome 00?.png mono.pdf
convert -monochrome 00?.png -density 200x200 mono200.pdf
convert -depth 1 00?.png  depth1.pdf
convert -monochrome -depth 1 00?.png  monoDepth1.pdf

ls -l *.pdf

   510362 default.pdf
   510350 mono.pdf
   510362 mono200.pdf
   510362 depth1.pdf
   510374 monoDepth1.pdf

for file in *.pdf ; do echo ' ' ; echo $file: ; pdfimages -list $file ; done

default.pdf:
page   num  type   width height color comp bpc  enc interp  object ID x-ppi y-ppi size ratio
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1     0 image    1700  2167  gray    1   8  image  no         8  0   200   200 70.1K 1.9%
   2     1 image    1700  2145  gray    1   8  image  no        22  0   200   200 67.8K 1.9%
   3     2 image    1700  2139  gray    1   8  image  no        36  0   200   200 97.8K 2.8%
   4     3 image    1700  2156  gray    1   8  image  no        50  0   200   200 80.2K 2.2%
   5     4 image    1700  2156  gray    1   8  image  no        64  0   200   200 89.9K 2.5%
   6     5 image    1700  2150  gray    1   8  image  no        78  0   200   200 85.2K 2.4%

mono.pdf:
page   num  type   width height color comp bpc  enc interp  object ID x-ppi y-ppi size ratio
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1     0 image    1700  2167  gray    1   8  image  no         8  0   200   200 70.1K 1.9%
   2     1 image    1700  2145  gray    1   8  image  no        22  0   200   200 67.8K 1.9%
   3     2 image    1700  2139  gray    1   8  image  no        36  0   200   200 97.8K 2.8%
   4     3 image    1700  2156  gray    1   8  image  no        50  0   200   200 80.2K 2.2%
   5     4 image    1700  2156  gray    1   8  image  no        64  0   200   200 89.9K 2.5%
   6     5 image    1700  2150  gray    1   8  image  no        78  0   200   200 85.2K 2.4%

mono200.pdf:
page   num  type   width height color comp bpc  enc interp  object ID x-ppi y-ppi size ratio
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1     0 image    1700  2167  gray    1   8  image  no         8  0   508   508 70.1K 1.9%
   2     1 image    1700  2145  gray    1   8  image  no        22  0   508   508 67.8K 1.9%
   3     2 image    1700  2139  gray    1   8  image  no        36  0   508   509 97.8K 2.8%
   4     3 image    1700  2156  gray    1   8  image  no        50  0   508   508 80.2K 2.2%
   5     4 image    1700  2156  gray    1   8  image  no        64  0   508   508 89.9K 2.5%
   6     5 image    1700  2150  gray    1   8  image  no        78  0   508   509 85.2K 2.4%

depth1.pdf:
page   num  type   width height color comp bpc  enc interp  object ID x-ppi y-ppi size ratio
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1     0 image    1700  2167  gray    1   8  image  no         8  0   200   200 70.1K 1.9%
   2     1 image    1700  2145  gray    1   8  image  no        22  0   200   200 67.8K 1.9%
   3     2 image    1700  2139  gray    1   8  image  no        36  0   200   200 97.8K 2.8%
   4     3 image    1700  2156  gray    1   8  image  no        50  0   200   200 80.2K 2.2%
   5     4 image    1700  2156  gray    1   8  image  no        64  0   200   200 89.9K 2.5%
   6     5 image    1700  2150  gray    1   8  image  no        78  0   200   200 85.2K 2.4%

monoDepth1.pdf:
page   num  type   width height color comp bpc  enc interp  object ID x-ppi y-ppi size ratio
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1     0 image    1700  2167  gray    1   8  image  no         8  0   200   200 70.1K 1.9%
   2     1 image    1700  2145  gray    1   8  image  no        22  0   200   200 67.8K 1.9%
   3     2 image    1700  2139  gray    1   8  image  no        36  0   200   200 97.8K 2.8%
   4     3 image    1700  2156  gray    1   8  image  no        50  0   200   200 80.2K 2.2%
   5     4 image    1700  2156  gray    1   8  image  no        64  0   200   200 89.9K 2.5%
   6     5 image    1700  2150  gray    1   8  image  no        78  0   200   200 85.2K 2.4%
```